# Rolling two dices. Count number of iterations for both of them to match condition

Tags: java, dice

In my program I have two dices with 100 faces. I make it count the amount of rolls it takes for dice one (d1) to equal 99 AND dice two (d2) to equal 26.

```
package diceroll;

import java.util.Random;

public class DiceRoll {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = 0;
    int d1 = 0;
    int d2 = 0;

    while (d1 != 99 && d2 != 29) {
        d1 = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        d2 = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        count += 1;
    }
    System.out.println(count + " " + d1 + " " + d2);
}
```

When using the AND operator (&&) the while loop only works until one of the numbers is found, however when using the OR operator (d1 != 99 || d2 != 29) the while loop works until both of them are matched.

Can somebody explain why OR gives the expected results, whilst AND doesn't?

Comment: Write down the logic table.

Comment: you do want the value of d==99 and d2==29 in same roll ?

Comment: Writing `while (!(d1 == 99 && d2 == 29))` could have helped your understanding. Applying DeMorgan's transformation law to that gives the expression you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop

```
while (condition)
```

keeps looping until `condition` is false. Your loop is:

```
while (d1 != 99 && d2 != 29) {
```

but *both* halves of the test must be true for the whole condition to be true. Once one of the numbers matches, one half will be false (it will not be not equal).

If you change the condition to OR:

```
while (d1 != 99 || d2 != 29) {
```

then only *one* side needs to be true for the whole condition to be true, or put another way, *both* sides need to be false for the whole condition to be false. This OR condition can be expressed in English as "while either of the numbers is not the target". Only when *both* numbers are their target is the entire condition false.

Answer (score 0):

That's how `AND` works. It just looks for a single expression to return `false` to terminate the loop. It doesn't bother whether `d1` is `69` or not, if `d2` becomes `29` and vice versa.

But when you use `OR`, it checks for both the conditions. That way, even if `d2` becomes `29` and `d1` is still not `69` it continues to loop till `d1` becomes 69, and thus evaluating to `false` only when both the conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `&&`, if one of the dice doesn't equal the desired number, your conditional still returns `false`. For example, if `d1=99` and `d2=1`, your `while` conditional would read: `99 != 99 && 1 != 29` -> `false && true` -> `false`. So it exits.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I understand it now. By using while not and OR logic, I created NOR logic which has the following table:

A B Z

0 0 1

0 1 0

1 0 0

1 1 0

Thanks for the help guys! :)